# Please help me with C++ Namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

namespace A {
    int a = 10;
    void get_value(){ std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl; }
}

namespace B {
    int b;
    void get_value(){ std::cout << "b =" << b << std::endl; }
}

void set_B();

int main(){

    using namespace A; 
    get_value(); 
    set_B();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void  set_B(){
    using namespace B;
    b = 15;
    get_value();    // Why call to get_value() is ambiguous, error is not generated here ?
 }
```

Why call to `get_value()` inside `set_B()` function is not ambiguous ( `A::get_value()` or `B::get_value()`) as both appear as `::get_value()` inside `set_B()`.

Comment: Why do you think they both appear as `::get_value()`?

Comment: @juanchopanza  as using namespace B; statement inside set_B() introduces B::get_value() into global namespace and statement using namespace A; inside main() introduces A::get_value() into global namespace.

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: @matt thanks for the link .  I know using namespace std; is not a good practice. That's why I have used std::cout in the above code. I am beginner in C++ that's why I'm playing with the code. :)

Comment: OK where you go wring is "introduces ... *into global namespace*". The `using` only have effect in their enclosing scope.

Comment: @juanchopanza So It means that using namespace A; inside main() has no effect inside the set_B() function. So get_value() inside set_B()  only refer to B::set_value().  Hence no error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`using namespace A;` isn't active inside `set_B` because it only appears inside `main`. It is limited to the scope in which it appears: the body of `main`.

Comment: But moving it to global namespace scope is causing call to get_value() is ambiguous compile time error .

Comment: @curious_kid Ah, that's right, `using namespace` does not import the namespace into the scope it appears. But its effect is limited to that scope. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

because `A::get_value` and `B::get_value` arn't normally visible in the global scope. the `using namespace` statement makes the declarations in that namespace visible inside `set_B`.